# Is the composition of a monotonic/strictly increasing/decreasing function $f$ with another function $g$ also monotonic/strictly increasing/decreasing?

Tags: calculus, functions

I believe, I read a theorem that stated that if $f(x)$ is a monotonic increasing/decreasing or strictly increasing/decreasing then $g(f(x))$ is also monotonic increasing/decreasing or strictly increasing/decreasing. Is this true?

Comment: No. $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @s5s, I think you forgot to add some condition on $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true in general since it depends also from $g(x)$.

Let consider for example

- $f(x)=x$
- $g(x)=1$

More in general for $f(x)$ strictly increasing we have

- $g(x)$ strictly increasing $\implies g(f(x))$ strictly increasing
- $g(x)$ monotonic increasing $\implies g(f(x))$ monotonic increasing
- $g(x)$ strictly decreasing $\implies g(f(x))$ strictly decreasing
- $g(x)$ monotonic decreasing $\implies g(f(x))$ monotonic decreasing

but for $f(x)$ monotonic increasing we have

- $g(x)$ strictly increasing $\implies g(f(x))$ monotonic increasing
- $g(x)$ monotonic increasing $\implies g(f(x))$ monotonic increasing
- $g(x)$ strictly decreasing $\implies g(f(x))$ monotonic  decreasing
- $g(x)$ monotonic decreasing $\implies g(f(x))$ monotonic decreasing

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general. Take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, for instance.